# Html.ActionLink Run My Action for several times in MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

in view:

```
<%=Html.ActionLink(dr["ProductLinkLabel"].ToString(), "downloadFile", "Home", new { LinkID = dr["ProductLinkSN"]},null)%>
```

in controller:

```
    [NoCache]
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult downloadFile(int LinkID)
    {
        DataModelDataContext db =new DataModelDataContext();
        ProductLink_GetForeditResult link = db.ProductLink_GetForedit(LinkID).FirstOrDefault();
        string LinkUrl = link.ProductLinkUrl;
        db.ProductLink_DownloadUpdate(LinkID);
        string fileName = LinkUrl.Split('/').Last();
        return File(Server.MapPath(LinkUrl), System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName);
    }
```

`downloadFile` Method calls by `Html.ActionLink` for several times.
It must run at once, but call method random times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
<%=Html.ActionLink("LinkName","ActionName",new {id=1,name"test"})%>
```